# combine_pdf gem : PDF is Encrypted! Attempting to decrypt - not yet fully supported

Tags: ruby, encryption, ruby-on-rails-5, combine-pdf

Trying to merge PDF file

I'm using version (1.0.16) and tried (1.0.21) also, but still getting this error PDF is Encrypted! Attempting to decrypt - not yet fully supported.

I'm able to open the file in preview without password.

I see this issue, which is already discussed issue[#66](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/issues/66) and closed but still getting error, any help here?

https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/issues/196

Comment: Please point out the issue by using a link and check for which version it is closed.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes updated

Comment: Great that goes a long way. Which error are you receiving - is it literally "not yet fully supported"? Any code you can share?

Comment: I have facing Same issue how can I solve it ?